# SQLite persisting data via php to MySQL server iOS

Tags: php, ios, mysql, sqlite, persist

Sorry in advance for sounding like a novice but I'm very new to app development and hope someone can help me!

I'm trying to create an iOS app that will store data locally when offline (i.e. an email address) and once connectivity to the internet is available will persist that data across to a server.

First I created an SQLite database which I done using the db browser tool, and everything for the most part is working the way it should. The app uses Core Data to persist to a SQLite DB.

Next I created a php file that would check for an internet connection then select the SQLite db and it's data then insert that data into a MySQL db.

This is where I got stuck. Am I right in thinking that the data saved in the SQLite db when running on a device is saved in the device's document directory?

If this is true then how do I gain access to it via the php file for it to be persisted over to MySQL server?

Am I missing something? What is the correct way of persisting this data across from the SQLite db on the device to my MySQL server?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to store your data in a cookie (the email address), and post to the server when online.  You would not need a offline client DB for data as small as an email address.

You could do this with AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript), posting to an awaiting php file based upon a Javascript file.

PHP communicates to MySQL very well with a LAMP/WAMP (Linux/Windows-Apache-MySQL-PHP) type server (or Ios version: IAMP?).  With AJAX, you would `$_GET` or `$_POST` to the PHP file, and then write the data (after sanitizing) to the MySQL database with either MYSQLI or PDO, preferably with a prepared statement.

To get the data back from the server, you would have another PHP file that could be loaded (again by AJAX) to query MySQL with a simple SELECT statement.

I am suggesting AJAX here because it would not require user interaction to post; you could set a timer to continually check for an internet connection, and post when it does come online.  You could also have a similar timer to sync with the server database.  Keep in mind, a timer based AJAX will put a constant load on your server, so this may not be too scalable.